# RFE: make the image button auto-link to a scaled-down version

Tags: feature-request, images

When posting example images, people often embed the full-sized link. This is great when that detail is important to answering the question, but also uses a lot of bandwidth. The Stack Exchange hosting service at Imgur automatically provides a scaled version — change `.jpg` to `l.jpg` at the end of a file. Could the code for adding images with the image button be changed to use this automatically (leaving the link to the original, unscaled version)?